# How to implement floating animation for items in a table view cell when using 3D Touch Peek feature?

Tags: ios, swift, 3dtouch

I've implemented 3D Touch Peek & Poop in my app using the following code sample:

```
extension ParentVC: UIViewControllerPreviewingDelegate
{
    func previewingContext(_ previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing,
                           viewControllerForLocation location: CGPoint) -> UIViewController?
    {
        guard let indexPath = mmTableView?.indexPathForRow(at: location) else { return nil }

        guard let cell = myTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) else { return nil }

        guard let detailsVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ChildVC") as?
            ChildVC else {
                return nil
        }

        detailsVC.manager = manager

        guard let detailsManager = detailsVC.manager else {
            return nil
        }
        previewingContext.sourceRect = cell.frame

        return detailsManager.previewDetails(indexPath: indexPath, detailsVC: detailsVC)
    }

    func previewingContext(_ previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing,
                           commit viewControllerToCommit: UIViewController)
    {
        navigationController?.pushViewController(viewControllerToCommit,
                                                 animated: true)
    }
}

class ParentVC: UIViewController
{
    var manager = Manager()

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if traitCollection.forceTouchCapability == UIForceTouchCapability.available
        {
            registerForPreviewing(with: self,
                                  sourceView: myTableView)
        }

        ...
}

class Manager: NSObject
{
    ...

        public func previewClothingDetails(indexPath: IndexPath, detailsVC: ChildVC) -> ChildVC
    {
        // Set text and image in ChildVC here

        detailsVC.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 0.0,
                                                height: 320.0)

        return detailsVC
    }
}
```

The result:

[image]

What I like to **achieve** is the following as can be seen in the iOS App Store:

[image]

If you notice, when the 3D Peek gesture is initiated, the text, image, as well as GET button has a **popping** animation, and appears to be **floating**, but the **cell does not move** with it, unlike mine.

How can I duplicate this animation?

Comment: Looks like the cell just doesn't have a background color?

Comment: @LinusGeffarth: makes sense, but how is that popping animation of the text, image, and button achieved in the AppStore app?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by that? I feel like it looks the same except for the white color.

Comment: Please look at the peek animation closely. On the AppStore you can clearly see the items in the table view cell has a floating animation, leaving a “shadow” underneath, whereas the items in my cell are static.